# how to bind different xml files to data grid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

we have 40 xml files.we want to bind to data grid dynamicliy.
40 xml files by diffrent structer
for example

```
a xml file :
<a>
<at1="val1" at2="val2"  >
<at1="val4" at2="val5" >
<at1="val7" at2="val8" >
<at1="val10" at2="val11" >
</a>

b xml file:
<b>
<at1="val1" at2="val2" at3="val3" >
<at1="val4" at2="val5" at6="val6">
<at1="val7" at2="val8" at3="val9">
<at1="val10" at2="val11" at3="val12">
</b>

c xml file:
<c>
<at1="val1" at2="val2" at3="val3"  at13="vall3">
<at1="val4" at2="val5" at6="val6"  at14="val14">
<at1="val7" at2="val8" at3="val9" at15="val15">
<at1="val10" at2="val11" at3="val12"  at16="val16">
</c>
```

dynamic code:

```
XElement TrackList = XElement.Parse("a.xml");

                    var atributs = TrackList.Descendants("a").Attributes();
                    foreach (var item in atributs)
                    {
                        DataGridTextColumn cc=new DataGridTextColumn();
                        cc.Header = item.Name;

                        Binding myBinding = new Binding("Attribute[" + item.Name.ToString() + "].Value");
                        myBinding.Source = datagrid1;
                        //LibViadat.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
                        cc.Binding = myBinding;
                        datagrid1.Columns.Add(cc);

                    }


                    datagrid1.DataContext = TrackList;
                    datagrid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```